Connecting to white listed API from Lambda inside private subnet with NAT gateway
My goal is to have a request sent from a lambda with a static IP address.
Here is the rough architecture:

I have created the following:

route table for private subnet (All traffic -> nat gateway)
route table for public subnet (All traffic -> internet gateway)
multiple API's inside private subnet
ALB pointing to private subnet, with IP whitelist
Route 53 record pointing to ALB ('test-api' in this case)
lambda inside VPC, within private subnet

However when i make requests from my lambda it is getting the following error:
ERROR! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test-api', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1434cb9450>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

I am able to make API requests from other API's to this 'test-api' domain with no issues (So the traffic is clearly being sent through NAT gateway)
and confirmed other IP's are unable to make requests to this domain.
I also am able to make requests to outside urls from this lambda (https://google.com was fine)
I looked at the ENI flow logs for this lambda and i dont see the NAT gateway IP's anywhere.
But I also confirmed an ENI was created, and the lambda is (seemingly) connected to the VPC and inside private subnets. I can see this under the 'VPC configuration' on the console.
Is there something I may be missing? It seems as though my lambda is not sending traffic through my NAT gateway and im not sure why.
# lambda
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  function_name = "${var.project_name}-lambda"
  role          = aws_iam_role.this.arn
  package_type  = "Image"
  timeout       = 120
  image_uri     = "${resource.aws_ecr_repository.this.repository_url}:latest"

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.this.id]
    subnet_ids         = data.aws_subnets.private.ids
  }

}

# security group
resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}"
  description = "SG for data loader lambda"
  vpc_id      = one(data.aws_vpcs.main.ids)
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

# IAM for lambda
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_lambda" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  name                 = "${var.project_name}-lambda"
  assume_role_policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_lambda.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_vpc_access" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}-lambda-vpc-access"
  description = "Allow lambda to create, describe and delete network interfaces so that it can access VPC resources"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
          "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Action = [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        Effect   = "Allow",
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

I then call my api simply like so inside the lambda:
import requests
def handler(event, context):
    try:
        requests.get(
            "https://my-api.com/test"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR!", e)
        raise e


I'm a little confused. Is the Lambda function calling an API endpoint on the Internet, or is it calling an Application Load Balancer inside the VPC that then connects to some other resources in side the VPC?

Sorry i will edit to make it more clear - there is an ALB in our public subnet which connects to an API (ECS task). The 'test-api' is a domain pointing to our alb.

But essentially as long as the IP the request is coming from is white listed the request should go through.

I'm still confused. Are you saying that the Lambda function calls an ALB, which sends a request to ECS, which then sends the request to an endpoint on the Internet, but the Lambda function isn't receiving the response? If so, where is it failing? Are there logs in the ECS task that show a request was received/processed/responded?

I added a diagram to try and make it a little clearer, sorry for the poor explanation. The lambda sends a request to the URL, which goes to the ALB, which has an IP whitelist which i believe is making the request not go through. So the request never even gets to ECS because its blocked by the ALB.
So it seems like the lambda isnt actually going through the nat gateway.

Oh! Are you saying the Lambda function calls an endpoint on the Internet that then comes back into the VPC, then through ALB and ECS? That's weird. Anyway, it is possible that the DNS name is being resolved differently from within the VPC. You should try and resolve the DNS name within the Lambda function (or other resource in the VPC) and check what IP address is returned -- it's possible that within the VPC it is being resolved to a private IP address, whereas from the Internet it is resolved to a public IP address.

Okay I will try that and see what I find - thank you! Would it make more sense to access ECS through a vpc endpoint from my lambda instead of all this?

Does the API need to be accessible from the internet or not?

It does, but only from certain IP’s.
